# Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)

Tags: node.js, linux, vue.js, npm

I have vue project on my ec2 instance

However when I'm trying to run `npm run serve` I'm getting this error

`Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)`

Check NPM / Node & OS versions here :

```
    [ec2-user@ip-123 project]$ npm -v
    6.14.13
    [ec2-user@ip-123 project]$ node -v
    v16.6.1
    [ec2-user@ip-123 project]$ node -p process.versions
    {
    node: '16.6.1',
    v8: '9.2.230.21-node.19',
    uv: '1.41.0',
    zlib: '1.2.11',
    brotli: '1.0.9',
    ares: '1.17.1',
    modules: '93',
    nghttp2: '1.42.0',
    napi: '8',
    llhttp: '6.0.2',
    openssl: '1.1.1k+quic',
    cldr: '39.0',
    icu: '69.1',
    tz: '2021a',
    unicode: '13.0',
    ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
    nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
 }
 [ec2-user@ip-123 project]$ node -p process.platform
 linux
 [ec2-user@ip-123 project]$ node -p process.arch
 x64
 [ec2-user@ip-123 project]$
```

I tried to delete `node_modules`

and reinstall it again but still got this error

Comment: What version of node sass in your package.JSON?

Comment: `"node-sass": "^4.9.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.1.0", ` I found this

Comment: You need node sass 6 to use with node 16. For the version you have you need node 14. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass